# post request returning an error wtforms flask_sqlalchemy

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, wtforms

I'm trying to get a form that i've created with wtforms working and in my terminal all i'm seeing is this:

```
"POST /venues/create HTTP/1.1" 302
```

One minor side question is that I wish I could get a more descriptive error.  Is that possible?

But my main question is that when I submit the form it redirects to index and flashes the error message.  When it flashes the error, the correct name is displayed.  I'm using python3, flask, wtforms and flask-sqlalchemy.  I don't know what I'm doing wrong here.  This is the relevant code:

app.py:

```
class Venue(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'venue'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String)
    city = db.Column(db.String(120))
    state = db.Column(db.String(120))
    address = db.Column(db.String(120))
    phone = db.Column(db.String(120))
    image_link = db.Column(db.String(500))
    facebook_link = db.Column(db.String(120))
    seeking_talent = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=False, default=False)
    seeking_description = db.Column(db.String())
    genres = db.Column(db.String())
    website = db.Column(db.String())
    past_shows = db.relationship('Show', backref='shows', lazy=True)
```

I've tried this:

```
@app.route('/venues/create', methods=['POST'])
def create_venue_submission():
  error = False
  form = VenueForm(request.form)
  name = request.form.get('name')
  city = request.form.get('city')
  state = request.form.get('state')
  address = request.form.get('address')
  phone = request.form.get('phone')
  image = request.form.get('image_link')
  facebook = request.form.get('facebook_link')
  seeking = request.form.get('seeking_talent')
  seekingDesc = request.form.get('seeking_description')
  genres = request.form.get('genres')
  website = request.form.get('website')
  try:
    venue = Venue(name=name,
                  city=city,
                  state=state,
                  address=address,
                  phone=phone,
                  image_link=image,
                  facebook_link=facebook,
                  seeking_talent=seeking,
                  seeking_description=seekingDesc,
                  genres=genres,
                  website=website)
    db.session.add(venue)
    db.session.commit()
  except:
    error = True
    db.session.rollback()
  finally:
    db.session.close()
  if error:
    flash('An error occured. Venue ' + name + ' could not be listed.')
    return redirect(url_for('index'))
  else:
    flash('Venue ' + request.form['name'] + ' was successfully listed!')
    return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

and this:

```
@app.route('/venues/create', methods=['GET'])
def create_venue_form():
  form = VenueForm()
  return render_template('forms/new_venue.html', form=form)

@app.route('/venues/create', methods=['POST'])
def create_venue_submission():
  error = False
  #form = VenueForm(request.form)
  name = request.form['name']
  city = request.form['city']
  state = request.form['state']
  address = request.form['address']
  phone = request.form['phone']
  image = request.form['image_link']
  facebook = request.form['facebook_link']
  seeking = request.form['seeking_talent']
  seekingDesc = request.form['seeking_description']
  genres = request.form['genres']
  website = request.form['website']
  try:
    venue = Venue(name=name,
                  city=city,
                  state=state,
                  address=address,
                  phone=phone,
                  image_link=image,
                  facebook_link=facebook,
                  seeking_talent=seeking,
                  seeking_description=seekingDesc,
                  genres=genres,
                  website=website)
    db.session.add(venue)
    db.session.commit()
  except:
    error = True
    db.session.rollback()
  finally:
    db.session.close()
  if error:
    flash('An error occured. Venue ' + name + ' could not be listed.')
    return redirect(url_for('index'))
  else:
    flash('Venue ' + request.form['name'] + ' was successfully listed!')
    return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

forms.py:

```
class VenueForm(Form):
    name = StringField(
        'name', validators=[DataRequired()]
    )
    city = StringField(
        'city', validators=[DataRequired()]
    )
    state = SelectField(
        'state', validators=[DataRequired()],
        choices=[
            ('AL', 'AL'),
            ('WY', 'WY'),
        ]
    )
    address = StringField(
        'address', validators=[DataRequired()]
    )
    phone = StringField(
        'phone'
    )
    image_link = StringField(
        'image_link', validators=[URL()]
    )
    genres = SelectMultipleField(
        # TODO implement enum restriction
        'genres', validators=[DataRequired()],
        choices=[
            ('Alternative', 'Alternative'),
            ('Blues', 'Blues'),
            ('Classical', 'Classical'),
            ('Country', 'Country'),
            ('Electronic', 'Electronic'),
            ('Folk', 'Folk'),
            ('Funk', 'Funk'),
            ('Hip-Hop', 'Hip-Hop'),
            ('Heavy Metal', 'Heavy Metal'),
            ('Instrumental', 'Instrumental'),
            ('Jazz', 'Jazz'),
            ('Musical Theatre', 'Musical Theatre'),
            ('Pop', 'Pop'),
            ('Punk', 'Punk'),
            ('R&B', 'R&B'),
            ('Reggae', 'Reggae'),
            ('Rock n Roll', 'Rock n Roll'),
            ('Soul', 'Soul'),
            ('Other', 'Other'),
        ]
    )
    seeking_talent = SelectField(
        'seeking_talent', validators=[DataRequired()],
        choices=[
            (True, 'Yes'),
            (False, 'No')
        ]
    )
    seeking_description = StringField(
        'seeking_description'
    )
    facebook_link = StringField(
        # TODO implement enum restriction
        'facebook_link', validators=[URL()]
    )
    website = StringField(
        # TODO implement enum restriction
        'website', validators=[URL()]
    )
```

new_venue.html

```
<div class="form-wrapper">
    <form action="/venues/create" method="POST" class="form">
      <h3 class="form-heading">List a new venue <a href="{{ url_for('index') }}" title="Back to homepage"><i class="fa fa-home pull-right"></i></a></h3>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        {{ form.name(class_ = 'form-control', id=name, autofocus = true) }}
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
          <label>City & State</label>
          <div class="form-inline">
            <div class="form-group">
              {{ form.city(class_ = 'form-control', placeholder='City', id=city, autofocus = true) }}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              {{ form.state(class_ = 'form-control', placeholder='State', id=form.state.id, autofocus = true) }}
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="address">Address</label>
        {{ form.address(class_ = 'form-control', id=address, autofocus = true) }}
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
          <label for="phone">Phone</label>
          {{ form.phone(class_ = 'form-control', placeholder='xxx-xxx-xxxx', id=phone, autofocus = true) }}
        </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="genres">Genres</label>
        <small>Ctrl+Click to select multiple</small>
        {{ form.genres(class_ = 'form-control', placeholder='Genres, separated by commas', id=form.genres.id, autofocus = true) }}
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="seeking_talent">Is Venue currently seeking talent?</label>
        {{ form.seeking_talent(class_ = 'form-control', id=form.seeking_talent.id, autofocus = true) }}
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="seeking_description">What kind of music are you looking for?</label>
        {{ form.seeking_description(class_ = 'form-control', id=seeking_description, autofocus = true) }}
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
          <label for="facebook_link">Facebook Link</label>
          {{ form.facebook_link(class_ = 'form-control', placeholder='http://', id=facebook_link, autofocus = true) }}
        </div>
      <div class="form-group">
          <label for="image_link">Image of Venue</label>
          {{ form.image_link(class_ = 'form-control', id=image_link, autofocus = true) }}
        </div>
      <div class="form-group">
          <label for="website">Website</label>
          {{ form.website(class_ = 'form-control', id=website, placeholder='http://', autofocus = true) }}
        </div>
      <input type="submit" value="Create Venue" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">
    </form>
  </div>
```

What am I doing wrong?